# How List<> object reference works?

Tags: java, android, list, object

I have `List<CapturedImage> capturedImageList = assingedFromSomewhere();`

What will happen if I delete element `0` of `capturedImageList` which is currently being processed by a separate `Thread`?

```
// Procesing a Thread
capturedImage.deleteImageFile(capturedImageList.get(0).getAbsolutePath());

if (capturedImage.saveToDisk(bitmap_original)) {
    // Note : Thred process in not completed yet
    capturedImageList.remove(0);
    capturedImageList.add(0, capturedImage);
}
```

1. Will the file will get deleted?
2. If so, how is the object reference is working here?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this but i believe you will encounter a concurrent modification exception,
if you try to manipulate a resource which is already in use.. instead you can use a
**CopyOnWriteArrayList**